# How can I divide an index in lucene?

Tags: lucene, indexing

I need to divide an index in two ones randomly in order to get an index for training and other for testing. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by dividing the index, but

To create a copy of the index, you can simply copy the entire index directory to a new location.  Make sure the index is not currently in use when you create the copy (that is, no `IndexReaders` or `IndexWriters` are currently open on it), as that can lead to locking issues on the new copy.